# Laravel 4.2 eloquent response to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

> JQuery AJAX code:

```
$('#seachInput').keyup(function() {
        var searchInput = $('#seachInput').val();

        $('tbody').html("");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/public/get-all-companies-ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {searchInput: searchInput, _token: token},
            success: function(data) {
console.log(data[0].companyStatus.labal; // here is the relationship

}
});
```

> Controller

```
public function getCompanies() {
        $searchInput = Input::get("searchInput");
$companies = Company::where('name', 'like', $searchInput.'%') -> with('totalSales', 'companyStatus', 'userAssigned') -> limit(100) -> get();

return $companies;
}
```

> Question is

How I return the the company status from the jquery while i have a working relation between company and company status? It prints only in the Controller because in the controller the companies variable have the relationship while in the JQuery it is a normal array.

Comment: you seem to be coding it right. Can you please write that what output are you expecting at jQuery end?
Also, it would be helpful if you can share print of `$companies` array at Laravel end

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal $companies shouldnt be an array it should be an object i need to access eloquent in this object

Comment: You can set json response using `return Response::json($companies);`